# How do I detect in code from which View POST was made, in MVC 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am wondering how to check in an Action, from which View I made POST to it.
So after the action is complete I can make a return back to that same View.

Like:

```
if (enteredfromView1)
{
    return RedirectToAction("View1","Controller");
}
else
    return RedirectToAction ("View2","Controller");
```

Comment: Maybe it is OK to pass some variable through URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Request.UrlReferrer to implement this.

```
public ActionResult TryMeOut()
{
   TempData["ReturnPath"] = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
   //return your users to the correct view.
}
```

If this is not what you are looking for, than you should take a look at this post. Maybe this helps you out: [Obtain View name in Controller, ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610855/obtain-view-name-in-controller-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

If your action is that dynamic (in that several views could redirect to the same action), you can use the UrlReferrer property of the Request.  More information can be found on the [MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx).  You would have to implement a `Redirect("URL")` instead, or parse the URL to infer the controller and view.

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden input into your forms that indicates the name of the view.

```
<input type="hidden" id="ViewName" name="ViewName" value="View1" />
```

Then in your action just use `Request.Form["ViewName"]` to retrieve it.

```
string viewName = Request.Form["ViewName"];

switch (viewName)
{
    case "View1":
        return RedirectToAction("View1","Controller");

    case "View2":
        return RedirectToAction("View2","Controller");

    // ...

    default:
        return RedirectToAction("SomeDefault", "Controller");
}
```