# Obtain the type of view that is calling the controller in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I know that this question may be flagged as duplicate to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610855/obtain-view-name-in-controller-asp-net-mvc) but my question is I need to obtain some reference not URL for the view that called the Controller action. I need to determine an attribute for the model based on the View with a code such as

```
public ActionResult Create(message message)
        {
        switch (View.type)
{
case("MSG"):
message.type = 0; // 0 for messages
case("Reminder"):
message.type = 1; // 1 for reminders
}
```

Comment: You'd have to pass in an identifier when you call it from your view.

Comment: @SamLeach At the moment I am setting my 'Message.Type' in the view but just wondering if there is anything built in in mvc that can handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you don't care what View was used, but what previous Controller action got you there.  In that case, you should add a field to you Model (or create a ViewModel) to indicate this information.

If you really care what View was used, then you have business logic in your View.  This is a bad thing.  Don't do that.